# Autocomplete on wrong screen?

Tags: front-end

I have a multiple monitor setup that Mathematica seems to be having trouble working with, displaying autocompletes on the wrong screen, opening notebooks off-screen, and so forth. Doing a little bit of trouble-shooting, the built in Wolfram System Information seems to show that two of my screens are located on top of each other:

[image: Wolfram System Information]

While the correct screen locations are as shown:

[image: Screen Layout]

How do I get Mathematica to detect the correct positioning of my various monitors? Running Windows 10 and Mathematica v12.1.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve my issue, but am still unclear about whether there would be a way to fix this within Mathematica or how this issue arose to begin with.

Exiting out of Mathematica completely, using my display control panel to "incorrectly" rearrange my display locations, restarting Mathematica (and confirming that it had updated to the incorrect locations), exiting out of Mathematica, using my display control panel to correctly arrange my displays, and then restarting Mathematica seems to have fixed the issue. Effectively, forcing Mathematica to recognize that my screen locations had changed and to update settings to reflect this change. I would hypothesize that some configuration setting got garbled, but is only updated if Windows flags display locations as having changed.

I would love to know more if anyone happens to have a better answer! Similarly, I'm nervous about this issue reappearing, given that it took few moments to go through the above process, rather than simply updating some system setting inside Mathematica directly.

Comment: This happened to me too! I couldn’t reproduce it once I had time to investigate but I reported the issue to Wolfram support. They asked me to confirm a few things but I couldn’t reproduce it so I think they just closed the bug report :/

Comment: @CATrevillian Glad to know I'm not the only one! I haven't had a recurrence of this issue since going through the above rigamarole, but I also haven't changed any monitor or graphics card settings.